File.createTempFile("name",".extension") will create a file in memory or on the Hard Drive?
i would like to know if the function
 File my_file =  File.createTempFile("name",".extension") 

will create a file using the pc memory or the pc HD.
Thanks in advance

On the HD. What is your goal
?

If it’s in memory, it isn’t a file.  That’s pretty much the definition of what a file is.  So if a method says it creates a file, it creates a file, not a memory allocation.

@VGR. Yes and no. If I do touch /dev/shm/deleteme that file is in memory, not on disk

It would be more correct to say in the filesystem rather than in the hard drive.

my goal was to avoid proliferation of temporary pdf files that i create on fly upon servlet request and served to clients requesting those files @g00se

On the hard drive. From the docs (emphasis mine):

Creates an empty file in the default temporary-file directory, using the given prefix and suffix to generate its name. Invoking this method is equivalent to invoking createTempFile(prefix, suffix, null).

